# display only first div tag inside main div

Tags: html, css

I have four div tags. One of them is `.main` div. The rest of the are inside `.main` with `.sub` classes. What I want is first to show 1st div tag inside `.main` and the rest will be placed on the right side of the first div tag but the `overflow` of the main div tag is hidden so that the other two div tags are not shown only the first is visible. I am trying to achieve this with [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/Ex9EC/1/). How can I achieve this?

```
.main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.sub {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
}

.blue { background: lightblue; }
.green { background: green; }
.orange { background: orange; }
```

Comment: Give different `id` to them and put `display:none` in the "green" and "orange"? And then you can change `style` with javascript if you want to show them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I've understood you correctly, and you want to see all three `sub` divs, one on the left, and two on the right, the problem is that you've set the widths to 100%, so there is no space to have them floating next to each other.

You need to set their widths so that they don't take up the full width of the container, for example they can each be 50% wide.

You also need to set the heights of the two divs on the right so that their total height is the same as the div on the left if you want them to line up.

**Update**:

To make it so that only the left div is visible initially, I think it's best you add another wrapper div around the the sub divs like this:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="sub blue"></div>
        <div class="sub green"></div>
        <div class="sub orange"></div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

With a width set to 200%.

```
.wrapper {
    width:200%;
}
```

Then when you want the right hand divs to become visible, you can slide them onto the screen by repositioning the wrapper div, either with a transform, relative position, or margin setting.

[Updated fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BX5My/1/)

Comment: Yes I do want to place 1 div on the left and other 2 on the right but the all div should take 100% width and only make visible the first one. Then I will have a next button. When user clicks on next button then the first div will move on the left and become invisible and second div will animate and become visible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but i have found that if you have space below the first item in this situation it won't work as expected..

so make the height of sub match then it will work:

```
.sub {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ex9EC/2/

probably this is totally wrong approach though so wait for someone who knows to comment maybe?

Also I think there might be something about how the position of the outer/container div has to be set (to relative,absolute or fixed) which is why i added that but it seems to work without it too:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ex9EC/3/